# ArcGIS Pro - Interpolating causes longitudinal extent to increase (i.e. range(-180,180) instead of range(165,178))

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation

I tried both IDW and (Ordinary)Kriging interpolations, setting both processing extent and mask (in the environment pane) for the study area, which works initially, as can be seen with the Raster layer on the right image. However, looking at raster information and extent, there are more columns than there should be and the longitudinal range goes from range(165,178) to range(-180,180).
I have tried using shapefile boundaries provided in the "living atlas" and a 25m resolution DigitalElevationModel (DEM) as the processing extent and masking but it still did not help. 
Is this a bug?
[image]